# Declaring names of environments in labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, cleveref, sv-classes

I am using the `svmono` class with `envcountsame` option. Unfortunately, this ha issues with `cleveref` because of how the class defines its environments.

For example, if I have `\begin{proposition}\label{xyz}` and call `\Cref{xyz}`, the output will always be **Theorem xyz** rather than **Proposition xyz***, and similarly for any other environments.

A workaround is to add the name of the environment into the label command: so, instead of `\begin{proposition}\label{xyz}` I use `\begin{proposition}\label[proposition]{xyz}` and this seems to work.

However, I am now encountering that the environments cleveref recognizes in this way are limited. For example, this does not seem to work with `question` or `exercise`, etc., and cleveref will actually display **??? xyz**, with no environment name.

How can I add these environments for `cleveref` to properly get the environment name to display? FWIW, I *did* load `cleveref` after all other packages.

Comment: Please clarify: Are `question` and `exercise` environments set up by the `svmono` class? If so, are they theorem-like environments?

Comment: @Mico: Yes, the actual class file declares these environments the same way it does theorem, proposition, etc., there’s no difference between them. I’m starting to think it may actually be an internal issue of cleveref itself, not specific to svnmono (the earlier issues notwithstanding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Remark: Shortly after I posted the answer shown below, the OP updated the posting to mention that the `svmono` class is loaded with the option `envcountsame`. That's a crucial bit of information. The following answer does *not* apply if `envcountsame` is in force.]

Not all conceivable environment names are known *a priori* to `cleveref`. Happily, the `cleveref` package provides the macro `\crefname` to let users spell out how environments with heretofore unknown-to-cleveref names should be labelled. E.g.,

```
\crefname{exercise}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
```

Incidentally, what is the basis for your claim that "if [when using the `svmono` document class] I have `\begin{proposition}\label{xyz}` and call `\Cref{xyz}`, the output will always be **Theorem xyz** rather than **Proposition xyz**"? According to the following MWE (minimum working example), I'd say that this claim does not appear to be correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\crefname{exercise}{exercise}{exercises}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} aaa     \label{aaa}\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition} bbb \label{bbb}\end{proposition}
\begin{exercise} ccc    \label{ccc}\end{exercise}
\begin{question} ddd    \label{ddd}\end{question}

\obeylines
\cref{aaa}, \Cref{aaa} 
\cref{bbb}, \Cref{bbb}
\cref{ccc}, \Cref{ccc}
\cref{ddd}, \Cref{ddd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies. I forgot that the issue was adding the envcountsame option in the document class. (Edited main post to reflect this.) I tried it with your MWE, and confirmed that with \documentclass[envcountsame]{svmono} the issue resurfaces. Alas, the \crefname workaround does not seem to work in this case. So indeed, it is some kind of conflict between the option and cleveref.

Comment: I really am sorry for forgetting that crucial bit of info. However, the ```envcountsame``` is quite important, especially for long bodies of work. Is there any standard workaround to this clash? Or perhaps an alternative to this option? Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @Skeptic that is why more or less every question should include a complete example document that shows the problem. If you provide a test case you can not omit details