# numbering section lemma theorem etc

Tags: numbering

A referee suggests that

> The style of numbering of results in the paper make them hard to find.
> I would suggest at least numbering by section and also probably using the same
> counter for theorems, lemmas, definitions etc.

My code in overleaf is as follows, use the springer template, but I can not figure out how to make it as the referee expected. Very much appreciate the help!

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto) 
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bbm}

%Includes "References" in the table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx,cite}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red}

\textwidth=15.0cm \textheight=21.0cm \hoffset=-1.1cm \voffset=-0.5cm

%\textwidth=13.8cm \textheight=21.7cm \topmargin=0.0cm
%\oddsidemargin=1.0cm \evensidemargin=1.0cm

%\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}

\iffalse
\setlength{\textwidth}{170mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{215mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Leb}{Leb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cor}{Cor}
\DeclareMathOperator{\interior}{int}
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Emb}{Emb}

\newcommand{\cqfd}{{\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em\hbox{}
\nobreak\hfil $\square$\qquad\parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\par\medskip}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\newcommand{\dt}{\partial_t}
\newcommand{\dx}{\partial_x}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\eps}{ \varepsilon}
\newcommand{\Lip}{\mbox{\rm Lip}}
\newcommand{\pr}{{\bf \textit{Proof : }}}
\newcommand{\ph}{ \varphi}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\def\bR{\mathbf{R}}
\def\bS{\mathbf{S}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{Convention}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
% for article


%Import the natbib package and sets a bibliography style
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}

content

\bibliography{bibtext}


\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the numbering will comply with the referee's suggestion.

Comment: i updated my code, springer template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a template, it's best to stick to their setup. And for this Springer class (`svjour3`), it already defines a number of theorem-like structures.

The class provides an option to have all theorem-like structures use the same counter: `envcountsame`

[image]

```
\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsame]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\numberwithin{theorem}{section}

\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{Convention}
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem} A theorem \end{theorem}
\begin{corollary} A corollary \end{corollary}
\begin{proposition} A proposition \end{proposition}
\begin{lemma} A lemma \end{lemma}
\begin{definition} A definition \end{definition}
\begin{remark} A remark \end{remark}
\begin{notation} A notation \end{notation}
\begin{convention} A convention \end{convention}
\begin{assumption} An assumption \end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

---

A more crude way to achieve this would be to revoke the counters associated with already-defined theorem-like structures, and re-establish them as aliases of the `theorem` counter.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\numberwithin{theorem}{section}% Number theorems within sections: <section>.<theorem>
\makeatletter
% Remove existing theorem-like counters
\let\c@corollary\relax% Corollary
\let\c@proposition\relax% Proposition
\let\c@lemma\relax% Lemma
\let\c@definition\relax% Definition
\let\c@remark\relax% Remark
\makeatother

% Slave duplicate counter (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65827/5764)
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{corollary}{theorem}% Corollary numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newaliascnt{proposition}{theorem}% Proposition numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newaliascnt{lemma}{theorem}% Lemma numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newaliascnt{definition}{theorem}% Definition numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newaliascnt{remark}{theorem}% Remark numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}% Notation numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{Convention}% Convention numbering: <section>.<theorem>
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}% Assumption numbering: <section>.<theorem>

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{6}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem} A theorem \end{theorem}
\begin{corollary} A corollary \end{corollary}
\begin{proposition} A proposition \end{proposition}
\begin{lemma} A lemma \end{lemma}
\begin{definition} A definition \end{definition}
\begin{remark} A remark \end{remark}
\begin{notation} A notation \end{notation}
\begin{convention} A convention \end{convention}
\begin{assumption} An assumption \end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can we directly change the cls file in the springer template?

Comment: @jason: I found out that the class provides an option `envcountsame`. This achieves what you want without having to change the class, or use other packages.

Comment: Thanks! It works well! I added them before \begin{document}, but can we put these codes into cls file?

Comment: @jason: Yes you can. But if this is for an actual journal submission, they will certainly use their unmodified `svjour3.cls` to process your document.

Comment: The option `envcountsame` has issues with cleveref, as lemmas, propositions, etc. are all referred to as "Theorem" (see, e.g., [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595401/svjour3-with-envcountsame-breaks-autoref-and-cleveref)). This solution seems to work quite fine instead